# Как отправлять с двух серверов на питоне сообщения в одного бота?

Tags: python, telebot, сервер

У меня есть два сервера на Python, которые парсят сайт. Данных много, и все они должны присылать данные в одного бота в телеграмм. Telebot ругается, не дает так сделать. Как сделать так, чтобы на двух серверах можно было использовать метод `send_message` в одного бота? Или есть какие-либо другие решения? Заранее спасибо!